# Algorithm to check whether students can be allocated to classes as per their preferences

Tags: algorithm

In a coding hackathon I got following problem :

There are K  classes each having certain capacity. There are N students and each has one or two class preference. We need to print "YES" if all the students can be allocated to a class or else "NO".

For example :

```
N = 4
K = 3
capacity = {2,1,1}
preference = {"0","0,2","1","2"}
```

There are 4 students and 3 classes and as per their preferences following classes can be allocated:

| Student | Classes |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |

So the answer for the above scenario will be "YES"

What will be algorithm approach to solve the above problem?

Update:

I used Christian's explanation below to come up with following solution:

```
import java.util.*;
public class StudentAllocation{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        int N = 4;
        int K = 3;
        int capacity[] = {2,1,1};
        String preference[] = {"0","0,2","1","2"};
        System.out.println(canAllocate(N,K,capacity,preference));
    }
    public static String canAllocate(int N,int K,int c[],String p[]){
        //Creating nodes for each student and capacity*class
        //Also making one node for source and on node for sink
        HashMap<String,Integer> nm = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        int n = 1;
        for(int i = 0;i < N;i++){
            nm.put("s"+i,n++);
        }
        for(int i = 0;i < c.length;i++){
            for(int j = 0;j < c[i];j++){
                nm.put("c"+i+j,n++);
            }
        }
        n = n+1;
        int[][] g = new int[n][n];
        //connecting source to all student nodes
        for(int i = 1;i <= N;i++){
            g[0][i] = 1;
        }
        //connecting all capacity*class nodes to sink
        for(int i = N+1;i < n-1;i++){
            g[i][n-1] = 1;
        }
        //Connecting student node to all the capcity node of class of his preference
        for(int i = 0;i < p.length;i++){
            String ps = p[i];
            String pst[] = ps.split(",");
            for(int j = 0;j < pst.length;j++){
                for(int k = 0;k < c[Integer.parseInt(pst[j])];k++){
                    g[nm.get("s"+i)][nm.get("c"+pst[j]+k)] = 1;
                    g[nm.get("s"+i)][nm.get("c"+pst[j]+k)] = 1;
                }
            }
        
        }
        //Using Ford Fulkerson to callculate max flow
        // If max flow is equal to no of students then each student can be allocated to any class of his preference
        //Making residual graph
        int rg[][] = new int[n][n];
        
        for(int i = 0;i < n;i++){
            for(int j = 0;j < n;j++){
                rg[i][j] = g[i][j];
            }
        }
        
        int parent[] = new int[n];
        int max_flow = 0;
        int count = 0;
        while(bfs(rg,0,n-1,parent)){
            count++;
            
            int path_flow = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            for(int i = n-1;i != 0;i = parent[i]){
                path_flow = Math.min(path_flow,rg[parent[i]][i]);
            }
            
            max_flow = max_flow + path_flow;
            for(int i = n-1;i != 0;i = parent[i]){
                rg[parent[i]][i] -= path_flow;
                rg[i][parent[i]] += path_flow;
            }
            
        }
        if(max_flow == N){
            return "YES";
        }
        return "NO";    
        
    }
    
    public static boolean bfs(int rg[][],int u, int v, int[] p){
        ArrayDeque<Integer> q = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
        q.offer(u);
        int marked[] = new int[rg.length];
        while(!q.isEmpty()){
            u = q.poll();
            marked[u] = 1;

            for(int i = 0;i < rg[u].length;i++){
                if(marked[i] != 1 && rg[u][i] > 0){
                    p[i] = u;
                    q.add(i);
                    if(i == v){
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: does this hlep you? https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/49153/assignment-based-on-ranked-preference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a bipartite graph with student nodes on one side, and then on the other side create class*capacities nodes.  Each node represent one spot in a class.

An edge from a student to a class node represents that this student is willing to take this spot.  Note that a student is willing to take any spot in a class it has a preference to.

The problem then is to find a perfect matching in this graph. If such a matching exists it is a "YES", if not it is a "NO".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive algorithm. We consider the last student, try their first choice and
check if the problem for the remaining n-1 students can be solved. If not, try the second
choice (if any), and again, check the problem for the remaining students.

Here is an implementation in PHP (you can test it [here](https://3v4l.org/JMECG#v7.4.21)):

```php
<?php
function isSolvable($choices1, $choices2, $capacities, $n)
{
    if($n==0)
        return true; // No students left to allocate

    // First choice of student $n
    $c1 = $choices1[$n-1];
    if($capacities[$c1]>0)
    {
        $capacities[$c1]--;
        if(isSolvable($choices1, $choices2, $capacities, $n-1))
            return true;
        $capacities[$c1]++;
    }

    // Second choice of student $n
    $c2 = $choices2[$n-1];
    if($c2>=0 && $capacities[$c2]>0)
    {
        $capacities[$c2]--;
        if(isSolvable($choices1, $choices2, $capacities, $n-1))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

$choices1 = [0, 0, 1, 2];
$choices2 = [-1, 2, -1, -1];
$capacities = [2, 1, 1];
echo isSolvable($choices1, $choices2, $capacities, count($choices1)) ? 'YES' : 'NO';
?>
```